# Where to download Sketch’s version of the SF font?

Tags: fonts, sketch-app, ios, apple

I’ve been using Sketch’s default iOS UI library, which uses Apple’s SF font. I already have a version of the SF font, but it doesn’t seem to be the same one Sketch defaults to. I’m sick of getting the missing-font notification. Does anyone know where to download the right version?

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt: Your edit seems to substantially change the question, invalidating the existing answers. Please ask a new question instead.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ugh. My edit was **exactly the same question**: The iOS UI Sketch Library asks for a version of SF Font which is not installed when you install Apple's SF Font. That's it. The same issue arises if you try their XD Library. All I did was give more detail. Cai thinks I invalidated his answer, but I didn't. His answer was always wrong. The OP, not having an Apple Dev account, simply assumed it was right.

Comment: @Django the UI kit you're using didn't exist at the time this question was asked and the font was absolutely not available for public download at the time; the correctness of my answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to download Apple's San Francisco font is from the Apple developer website:

- #### https://developer.apple.com/fonts/

The font isn't licensed for any general use at all. Only paid members of Apple's developer program are allowed to download it and are only allowed to use it for screen mockups, nothing more.

If you aren't an Apple developer you're out of luck. You could get someone who is an Apple developer to download it for you (but that would be against the license too). There are other (non-official) versions out there, but as you have seen you'll get missing font notifications and have to replace the font, which isn't ideal.

---

*Update: you no longer need to be a paid Apple developer to download San Francisco from https://developer.apple.com/fonts/, although the license hasn't changed and states only registered Apple developer are permitted to use the font ("You may use this Apple Font only for the purposes described in this License and only if you are a registered Apple Developer, or as otherwise expressly permitted by Apple in writing.")*.

Comment: You don’t need to be a developer to download SF from Apple. They allow anyone to do it

Comment: @Django that wasn't the case when I answered this question. Your edit to the question invalidated my (accepted) answer and changed the question. You really should have asked a new question

Comment: All I did was clarify what the original person was asking. It's *exactly* the same issue

Comment: @Django the original question was about using *another* version of the font and asked where to get the official font. You're using a different version of the font with a different UI kit and different software. The error may be the same but the situation it completely different

Comment: It seems you are right. Apple didn't release their iOS Sketch Library until a year after this question was asked. Ironic they both have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you already figured this out, but this is one of the top google results so I figured I'd post more links.
Apple used to provide the SF font to anyone as normal font download, but now they only allow it as a .pkg installer supposedly just for developers. Even as a developer, I had this issue:
[image]
"The San Francisco Pro Fonts installer does not allow its software to be installed here.

LINK TO GITHUB SFUIDisplay and SFUIText fonts:
https://github.com/AppleDesignResources/SanFranciscoFont

HOWEVER!!! While these are the exact same fonts, the names are written in full. For example:
Instead of SFUIDisplay-Heavy the name is SanFranciscoDisplay-Heavy

After installing, I still had to re-assign in sketch to use "SanFranciscoDisplay-Heavy" in place of "SFUIDisplay-Heavy"

Sounds like you already had that figured out, sorry can't get you better solution, but even though it's annoying, at least this works.

Comment: You'll still get the missing font notification, right? If so, this is not much of an improvement. And I'm not sure anybody else is allowed to distribute the font but Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://developer.apple.com/fonts/ to download San Francisco Font styles as a zip file. extract the font files from the SF-Font.dmg then open the SF Pro file folder. All the fonts will be listing there. Then open the FontBook app on you MacOS. Go back to the SF Pro folder and double-click the file the font you are missing. A prompt will then appear from FontBook for you to verify that you want it installed. Once you confirm installation, the font will now be upload to your system.
(Note: Might only work for MacOS systems.)

Comment: Once complete, if the font does not appear in Sketch app, open the Sketch file with the missing fonts. Then, in menu,  click on File> Replace missing fonts...